# Is there an operation for not less than or not greater than in python?

Tags: python, comparison-operators

Suppose I have this code:

```
a = 0
if a == 0 or a > 0:
    print(a)
```

That is: I want to do something when `a` is not negative.

I know that I can write `if a != 0:` to check whether `a` is not equal to `0`.

So, I tried using `if a !< 0:`, following similar logic. However, this is apparently not supported:

```
>>> if a !< 0:
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    if a !< 0:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Why is this syntax invalid? What can I use instead to simplify the conditional?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Instead of `a == 0 or a > 0`, simply use `a >= 0`.

See https://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons for a complete list of available comparison operators.

Comment: This works to check that something is not negative, but there could be other use cases where you would want to check if something was not < something else but >= would be fairly cumbersome. In that instance, "not" is the keyword you want

Answer (score 16):

`!<` does not work in Python; but `not` can be placed before a comparison to get the opposite effect, like so:

```
if not a < 70:
    print('The number is Not smaller than 70')
else:
    print('The number is DEFINITELY smaller than 70')
```

Answer (score 1):

Python does not provide e.g. a `!<` operator, because it is not needed. `if a == 0 or a > 0` means the same thing as `if a >= 0`.

Comment: "I'm not familiar with any language that does." +1 -- this isn't internal consistency. It's consistency with other languages so users from other backgrounds aren't confused.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the equal or greater than operator:

```
if a >= 0:
    print(a)
```